# Resolving names with saltstack

Tags: dns, salt-stack

I'm managing 4-19 computers with the Saltstack.

They obtain IP address using DHCP, and I'd like to avoid registering them with the company's DNS server.

My goal is to use names instead of IP addresses in the saltstack states and other configuration files.

I can retrieve IP addresses and save them to a pillar:

```
sudo salt \* network.ipaddrs | grep -v '\- 172' > /srv/pillar/ip.sls
sudo salt \* saltutil.refresh_pillar
```

If I save these lines in a script and put it to a cron, then I have actual IP addresses of all minions on all minions.

Then I can develop a new state that retrieves these values from pillar and updates `/etc/hosts` and add to the script the command applying that new state.
Some thing like

```
sudo salt \* state.apply update-hosts
```

IP addresses do not change often, so such update could run once per hour, or even daily should be enough.

What could be disadvantages of this solution?

Are there any existing Salt modules/states that I'm reproducing right now?

Comment: I've reinvented salt-mine. Also: https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/hostsfile-formula

Comment: Yes, using salt-mine you can do it. Combining reactors you can automate the update instead of using a schedule/cron.

Comment: Please don't invent a wheel. All these manipulations in my mind are overcomplecating simple DHCP/DNS configuration. You may want to quickly configure a separate DNS (bind, unbound, etc) server just for your purpose. Then just add MACs on the DHCP server in the static list and be done with it. This solution is simple and will be more prone to errors. Otherwise let's come back to hosts list instead of the DNS.

Comment: Could you share a sample config for unbound or bind, that would serve just specified MACs, ignoring other requests with respect of "upstream" DNS server? I would accept your answer, if it works. Indeed, I've come to hosts lists, that are automatically updated. With my small DNS server, I would need to automatically collect MACs - getting back to salt mine.